# pubsub message is getting delivered even after configuring dead letter topic

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a topic `topicA` with `deadLetterTopicA` associated with the subscription `subscriptionA` for the topic `topicA`.
Below is the configuration of the subscription `subscriptionA`

dead_letter_policy {
dead_letter_topic: "deadLetterTopicA"
max_delivery_attempts: 5
}

So if I can able to process the message I am calling `message.ack()` and if there is any error due to the disruption of other service I am dependent on, I am calling `message.nack()` so the the message will be redelivered. But, from the logs I can see that delivery attempts greater than 5 which was not expected.

`..... message_id is <messageId>, delivery attempt is 25 .......`

I dont have a subscription attached to the `deadLetterTopicA` so that I cannot debug what is going on the dead letter topic. But, I can check there is some request flow from the  google pubsub console.

[dead letter topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2GH7.png)

Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: There is something wrong with your confuguration. Can you extract and share the detail from GCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that you didn't [grant forwarding permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#grant_forwarding_permissions) to the Pub/Sub service account. You need to give the account `service-<project number>@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com` the publisher role on the dead letter topic and the subscriber role on the subscription to which the topic is attached.